# Programmatically pass unknown number of parameters in Python

Tags: python

I'd like an easy way to plug in a function and arguments to be executed later so I can have a kind of wrapper around it.

In this case, I'd like to use it to benchmark, example:

```
def timefunc(fn, *args):
   start = time.clock()
   fn(args)
   stop = time.clock()
   return stop - start
```

How do I pass arguments where the number of parameters aren't known?  How do I find the number of parameters?  How would I even call the function once I knew the number of parameters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just call the function like this:

```
fn(*args)
```

Comment: Sweet capers that was quick.

Just tried and it worked.  Thanks!

Comment: +1 and for further reading, http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/

Comment: For completeness, even though you didn't ask about it, note that if your function takes keyword arguments `timefunc(fn, *args, **kwargs)`, you can plug them into another function the same way: `fn(*args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 2):

MatrixFrog's answer is the correct one, but just to complete the picture. For finding out the number of arguments simply call `len`, because `args` is a tuple:

```
import time

def timefunc(fn, *args):
   start = time.clock()
   print len(args), type(args)
   fn(*args)
   stop = time.clock()
   return stop - start


def myfoo(a, b):
    c = a + b
    return c


timefunc(myfoo, 5, 6)
```

The print statement inside timefunc prints:

```
2 <type 'tuple'>
```

Since `args` is a tuple, you can access it like any other tuple.

Comment: Just curious, why are you timing the `print` as well as the function?

Comment: Chris I'm not timing it. I've just inserted it inside the function to show in the simplest way what the length and type of args is. It's just for debugging